# How to detect whether monitor turned off/on?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The problem is that on the text file i see all the results - `True` or `Not`.
Even when i turned off the monitor for 5-10 seconds and turned it on on, then the text file shows `True`.

Not sure why it's not detecting it.

I tried this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Management;

namespace Detect_Monitor_Settings
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern EXECUTION_STATE SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE esFlags);

        [FlagsAttribute]
        public enum EXECUTION_STATE : uint
        {
            ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED = 0x00000040,
            ES_CONTINUOUS = 0x80000000,
            ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED = 0x00000002,
            ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED = 0x00000001
            // Legacy flag, should not be used.
            // ES_USER_PRESENT = 0x00000004
        }

        StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(@"e:\monitordetector.txt");

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void DetectScreenName()
        {
           if (stopdetecting == false)
            {
                var query = "select * from WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams";
                using (var wmiSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("\\root\\wmi", query))
                {
                    var results = wmiSearcher.Get();
                    foreach (ManagementObject wmiObj in results)
                    {
                        // get the "Active" property and cast to a boolean, which should 
                        // tell us if the display is active. I've interpreted this to mean "on"
                        var active = (Boolean)wmiObj["Active"];
                        w.WriteLine(active.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }



        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        bool stopdetecting = false;
        int counttimer1 = 0;
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DetectScreenName();
            counttimer1 += 1;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            w.Close();
            stopdetecting = true;
            timer1.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your problem is here: `// tell us if the display is active. I've interpreted this to mean "on"`  Where did you get that assumption?  Can you provide some documentation?

Comment: This is already well covered in SO Q+A, no point in repeating it.  Google "wmi detect monitor turned on" to find them, the top five hits are all SO questions.  Enough to know to start looking for another project.

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation, `Active`

> Indicates the active monitor.

That doesn't mean the monitor isn't in a power saving mode. It just tells you whether it's disabled or not - usually, this is used to detect whether you have multiple monitors or not (e.g. "is the number of active monitors higher than 1?").